# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays

The problem:

> a program that updates a list of students’ grades after the end of drop period. The program should reads from the user number of students who dropped and their indexes, and then the program should copies the remaining student’s grades to new array. In addition, the program should display both the original and the updated list. [Hint: the new array must have suitable length equivalents to number of remaining students]

my code:

```
public class Q5{
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  public static void main (String args[]){

    double [] list={1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10};
    System.out.println("enter number of students who dropped:");
    int num=scan.nextInt();
    double [] list2 = new double [num];

    System.out.println("Enter index Of  the student who dropped ");
    for (int j=1 ; j<=num ; j++)
    {
      System.out.println("student" + j + ":");
      int index=scan.nextInt();
      list[index]=0;
    }

    int  j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.length ; i++)
    if (list[i]!=0)
    {
      list2[j]=list[i];
      j++;
    }
    System.out.print("The original list : " );
    for(int i=0; i<list.length ; i++)
    System.out.print(list[i] + " " );

    System.out.print("remaining students " );
    for(int i=0; i<list2.length ; i++)
    System.out.print(list2[i] + " " );
  }
}
```

what is the problem ? it is not working !!!
in Line 16 it says :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>       at Q5.main(Q5.java:23)

how I can correct this

Comment: Please paste the stack trace of error.

Comment: Please do the people that try to help you a tiny favor: What exactly do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: It would be good if you paste your error which would've printed in console.

Comment: Please note how much easier it is to read your code now that I've introduced consistent indentation.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the size of your `list2`.

You shouldn't set its size to `num`, but rather to the size of the original list. Because the `list2` is going to contain just as many elements as the original `list`. You need the `num` only to fetch that many inputs from the user and assign those indexes with the value *0*.

```
double[] list2 = new double[list.length]; // This should be the size of your list2
```

If you don't need to keep the original size, then you need to subtract the num from the original size, as suggested by [*@Joetjah*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950239/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception/19950323?noredirect=1#comment29692086_19950323).

```
double[] list2 = new double[list.length - num]; // This should be the size of your list2
```

Comment: Almost. `double [] list2 = new double [list.length - num];`

Comment: ok it almost works but this is the output enter number of students who dropped:
4
Enter index Of  the student who dropped 
student1:
1
student2:
2
student3:
3
student4:
4
The original list : 1 0 0 0 0 6 7 8 9 10 remaining students 1 6 7 8 9 10 0 0 0 0

Comment: @Joetjah - Thanks for that. I edited the answer. And Walaa, this edit should fix the array length problem as well, along with AIOOBE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail if the value entered by user is out of bounds for the array :

```
int index=scan.nextInt();
list[index]=0; // This may fail. Value entered by the user may exceed the array length
```

Comment: I mean it is risky to do so. Instead always have check before trying to access the value from array (as the value entered by the user may exceed the array length)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

You start of with 10 students. Say you want to drop 2 students. That means you set the `list2` size to 2.

Next thing you do, is trying to add all the students (10) from `list` to `list2`. But, `list2` is too small for this. Thus you get your Exception.

What you want, is this:

```
double [] list2 = new double [list.length - num];
```

Comment: it is not exactly 2 student cz the user will enter the number of students who dropped

Comment: @Walaa I ment as an example to illustrate in words what is happening, instead of in code. Then you can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Guess that problem with predefined array 'list'.

Step 1: Created the list with one of the initializing ways. Here the size is fixed.

Step 2: Took input from user : lets assume it is 11.

**list** doesn't need to contain the size given as input.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `list2` with wrong size.

You get from the user number of **dropped** students and then try to put in `list2` all the **remaining** students.

```
double [] list2 = new double [list.length - num];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Q5 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        System.out.println("enter number of students who dropped:");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        double[] list2 = new double[num - 1]; // should be num-1

        System.out.println("Enter index Of  the student who dropped ");
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            System.out.println("student" + j + ":");
            int index = scan.nextInt();
            list[index] = 0;
        }

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (list[i] != 0) {
                list2[j] = list[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The original list : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.print("remaining students ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list2[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

output is

```
 enter number of students who dropped:
    2
    Enter index Of  the student who dropped 
    student0:
    1
    student1:
     2
    The original list : 1.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 remaining students 1.0
```

Comment: Why the -1? Explain your answer.

Comment: If the given 2 students means the size of the array should be 1. right! array index starts from 0

Comment: For the 1st time index of student is 1 and again 2nd index is also 1. why?

Comment: Am I correct to say that instead of asking for the amount of students you drop, you ask for the studentnumber of the student to drop?

Comment: @joet ya u r right..see my edit its working fine for id 2 if i understood right

Comment: @MonickaAkilan Why would the user have to enter the index of the students he is dropping? You understood the code logic wrong, but I do understand where you are coming from! Funny way of thinking you have ;)

Comment: The program should reads from the user number of students who dropped and their indexes,  From this i think i understood right only.. first he enter the number of student to drop and he will give the student index number thats the way my code working. If you find any error please let me know always happy to learn

Comment: @MonickaAkilan remaining element is not only one element. If you drop 2 students out of 10 then the remaining number of students will be 8. right?

Comment: Ya you are right remaining students is wrong.. Sorry for that

Answer (score -1):

This will remove the exception you got. From next time you don't use static values.

**Edit:**
It is not a good practice to assign values to any variable by yourself. As the array is having size of 10. If user enters more than 10 students dropped then it will cause a problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q5 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        System.out.println("enter number of students who dropped:");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        double[] list2 = new double[list.length-num]; // should be num-1

        System.out.println("Enter index Of  the student who dropped ");
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            System.out.println("student" + j + ":");
            int index = scan.nextInt();
            list[index] = 0;
        }

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.err.println(""+list[i]);
            if (list[i] > 0) {

                list2[j] = list[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The original list : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.print("remaining students ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list2[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your edit, but how does the code solve that problem? What if the user enters 12? `double[] list2 = new double[list.length-num];` would be `double[-2]`...

Comment: That's why I mentioned there that not to specify the values in advance.

Comment: @Walaa you are getting this error because you have specified the size of list in advance. Or you can give the provision to user to enter the number of students less than **list.length()**